# Is it possible to have two Y Axis in a highstock chart from highcharts one on the left and another on the right?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to have 2 yAxis in a highstock chart from highcharts one on the left and another on the right ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried something ? Did you see Highcharts demos ?

Comment: I know this is possible for highcharts but I have not found a way or a demo for highstocks. When adding multiple Y axis on highstock it adds mini chart under the primary one.

Comment: It's called `navigator`. You can disable it, by default it's enabled. http://jsfiddle.net/PLF8A/

Comment: I am not talking about the navigator as I actually want it on my page, to take your example I just want to add the volume time series to the first chart and have an "additional" y axis displayed on the right of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simple example:
First you have to create your new yAxis and set it's position.

```
{
    title: {
        text: 'Other data panel'
    },
    top: 300,
    height: 100,
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2,
    opposite: true
}
```

Then, when you create your serie you in what yAxis it will be placed.

```
{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Other',
    data: otherData,
    yAxis: 2,
    dataGrouping: {
        units: groupingUnits
    }
}
```

You can see it [**working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VgCQV/).

Comment: Hey, thanks that's almost what I want however my goal would be to have the 2 y axis on the first chart and not the second I am starting to think that is not possible. I have modified your example but it is not quite there yet. http://jsfiddle.net/VgCQV/22/

Comment: Thanks that is almost what I want thanks for the tip, 
By the way  this is exactly what I wanted http://jsfiddle.net/VgCQV/37/